Proving triangle inequality for $\bigg( \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|^p dt \bigg)^\frac{1}{p}$ for $f \in \mathcal{C}\big( [0,1] \big)$ using Young inequality
Consider the space of continuous functions on the domain $[0,1]$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{C}\big([0,1]\big) = \big\{ f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \quad \text{s.t. } f \text{ continuous on } [0,1] \big\}
\end{equation}
and the mapping
\begin{equation}
f \mapsto \|f\|_p = \bigg( \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|^p dt \bigg)^\frac{1}{p}
\end{equation}
An exercise in my lecture notes asks to prove that $\mathcal{C}\big([0,1]\big)$ endowed with the above mapping is a normed space, and suggests to use Young's inequality
\begin{equation}
ab \leq \frac{1}{p}a^p + \frac{1}{q}b^p \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} \quad \forall \; p,q \in (0,\infty) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1
\end{equation}
I could easily prove that $\mathcal{C}\big([0,1]\big)$ is a real vector space and the positivity, homogeneity, and uniqueness properties of $\|f\|_p$ without using Young's inequality. So, I suppose this hint is meant for the triangle inequality. But I can see no way it can help.
My attempt 
The only way I could prove that the triangle inequality is satisfied is by observing that continuous functions on a closed interval are bounded, therefore
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{C}\big([0,1]\big) \subset L^{\infty}\Big([0,1], \mathcal{B}\big( [0,1] \big), \mathcal{Leb}([0,1])\Big) \subset L^{p}\Big([0,1], \mathcal{B}\big( [0,1] \big), \mathcal{Leb}([0,1])\Big) \quad \forall p \in [1,\infty]
\end{equation}
and noting that $\|f\|_p = \big( \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|^p dt \big)^\frac{1}{p}$ is a norm on $L^p(S,\Sigma,\mu) \quad \forall p \in (1,\infty) \quad \forall \mu(S)<\infty$

You can use Young's inequality to prove Hölder's inequality, and then use Hölder's inequality to prove the desired triangle inequality.
